# Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: client, client_id, delivered, id, kassa, no_boxes, notes, pub_date

Tags: django

Relevant parts of views.py and models.py are shown below. When I try to register a new order with potentially a new client I get the error shown in the title. I've tried to delete the line `new_order = Order(client = client_used, kassa = cd['kassa'], no_boxes = cd['no_boxes'], pub_date = timezone.now(), notes = cd['notes'])` but that didn't solve the problem.

I use Django version 1.10 and Python 2.7.10. Thanks in advance.

Views.py

```
def addclient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if Order.objects.filter(name = cd['name']).exists():
                client_used = Order.objects.get(name = cd['name'])
            else:
                 client_used = Client(name = cd['name'], address = cd['address'], city = cd['city'], date_created=timezone.now())
            client_used.save()

            new_order = Order(client = client_used, kassa = cd['kassa'], no_boxes = cd['no_boxes'], pub_date = timezone.now(), notes = cd['notes'])
            new_order.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return index(request)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = ClientForm()

    return render(request, 'clients/addclient.html', {'form': form})
```

Models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kassa = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_boxes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    delivered = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
         return "Order #" + str(self.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like written in the traceback there is no field `name` in the `Order` model.
Here is the wrong lines:

```
if Order.objects.filter(name = cd['name']).exists():
    client_used = Order.objects.get(name = cd['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you. It should be `Client` indeed.